# Monitor directory listing for changes?

Tags: linux, shell, directory, monitoring

On a unix system, how do I monitor (like how 'tail' works) a directory for changes made to files - either new ones created, or size changes, etc.

Looking for a command line tool rather than something to be installed.

Answer (score 5):

Most unix variants have an API for this, but it's not standardized. On Linux, there is [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). On the command line, you can use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait). Usage example:

```
inotifywait -m /path/to/dir | while read -r dir event name; do
  case $event in
    OPEN) echo "The file $name was created or opened (not necessarily for writing)";;
    WRITE) echo "The file $name was written to";;
    DELETE) echo "The file $name was deleted ";;
  esac
done
```

Inotify event types are often not exactly what you're trying to notice (e.g. OPEN is very wide), so don't feel bad if you end up making your own file checks.

Comment: This is the right answer because it shows how to use an API for monitoring the changes. The answer of ghostdog74 might work, but it has a cost of resources. What if you need to monitor 1000 directories?

Comment: Note: this answer only works if using linux kernel 2.6.13 or later.  Not sure about other Unicies.

Comment: could you please clarify what does *while **read -r dir event name;** do*  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can craft your own then if you don't want to install tools. Just an idea.
Create a base line file of your directory using `find` command. Use a loop or cron job, `find` the directory using the same parameters, and check the new file against the base line file. Use a tool like `diff`  to get the differences..

eg

```
find /path [other options] >> baseline.txt 
while true #or use a cron job
do
  find /path [same options] >> listing.txt
  diff baseline.txt listing.txt
  # do processing here...
  mv listing.txt baseline.txt  # update the baseline.
  sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Just for my reference - do things like this exist?

Comment: what "things" are you talking about? If you are talking about tools meant for such things, then yes. tools like tripwire, inotify etc...