# Script to extrar rar whenever a folder is created

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, automation

I want to:

1. Monitor a specific directory
2. If a new folder is created in this director and that folder contains rar multi-part files (rar, r01, r02, r03, r04 ... rn)
3. I need to extract those files in place

I can extract them by using command 
`unrar x <filename>.rar` but i don't know how to do steps 1 and 2 (automating the process).

My linux version is
`Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2 (2015-07-17)`

Comment: This should be 2 separate questions. Here is probably an answer to the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977890/monitor-directory-listing-for-changes

Comment: what if the new folder is created, and multipart rar files are in the process of being written into that directory?   You'd need to determine when it was done (all necessary files completely written out) before extracting.   This makes the process more complicated